# Whether these induced topologies are comparable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

$$\|x\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i|$$ and $$\|x\|_2=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^2)^{1\over 2}$$ these two norm induce topologies on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I want to know whether they are comparable?

Comment: It's a standard result that *all* norms on a finite-dimensional real vector space are equivalent.

Comment: I found this picture from Wikipedia: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_norms2.svg simply by Googling for [equivalent norms circle square](http://images.google.com/images?q=equivalent+norms+circle+square). I think it nicely illustrates the relation between various norms in $\mathbb R^2$; and it can help with your intuition for $n$-dimensional case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Kahen said, it is a standard result that all norms on a finite-dimensional real vector space are equivalent, however, in this particular case, it can be deduced with some ease (the following inequalities are immediate):

$$|x_i|\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

and

$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Neighbourhoods in the first topology are (unions of) arbitrarily small N-spheres, those in the second are (unions of) arbitrarily small N-cubes. It's obvious that every sphere contains a cube, which is enough for comparability; but also that every cube contains a sphere, so we have equivalence.